# Assigning a variable for 'iface.activeLayer()' when starting QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I use `iface.activeLayer()` intensively. Therefore, when I open QGIS, firstly I use the following script in QGIS Python Editor not to enter `iface.activeLayer()` everytime.

```
from qgis.utils import iface
L = iface.activeLayer()

def activeLayerChanged():
    L = iface.activeLayer()

iface.currentLayerChanged.connect(activeLayerChanged)
```

I thought it would work if I added it to `startup.py` file. I tried to add the script to `startup.py` but I got error: `name 'L' is not defined`.

How can I assing `iface.activeLayer()` to `L` (or any single-letter variable)  when starting QGIS, so that everytime I enter `L`, I can get the active layer?

Comment: Doesnt work with any variable when I try it. Like `a=1`, then `a` is not found in QGIS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a nice use case, but it's not supported nowadays out of the box.

The following is a small hack for you to get such result. Just write this code snippet into your `startup.py` script:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from console import console

if not console._console:
    # We need to initialize the console (QGIS knows how)
    # and respect the opened/closed state from last session
    iface.actionShowPythonDialog().trigger()
    console._console.setVisible(console._console.isUserVisible())

console._console.console.shell.runcode("""
L = None
def clc(layer):
    global L
    L = layer
iface.currentLayerChanged.connect(clc)
""")
console._console.console.shellOut.clearConsole()
```

Answer (score 7):

For this, I created a very small plugin with 2 files.

Create a directory in your `[...]/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/`, for example *StartupPlugin*.

Create in it the two files below.

Under QGIS, once, active the *StartupPlugin* in the plugin menu. Then, each times you'll load a project and change your active layer, the Python variable `L` is created / updated.

---

- **metadata.txt**:

```
[general]
name=
description=
about=
version=1.0
qgisMinimumVersion=3.0
author=
email=
repository=
```

- **__init__.py**:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from qgis.gui import QgsDockWidget
from console import show_console


def classFactory(iface):
    return StartupPlugin(iface)


class StartupPlugin:
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.sh = None
        self.iface.projectRead.connect(self.run)
        self.iface.currentLayerChanged.connect(self.activeLayerChanged)

    def initGui(self):
        pass

    def unload(self):
        pass

    def activeLayerChanged(self):
        if self.sh:
            self.sh.runsource("L = iface.activeLayer()")

    def run(self):
        pc = show_console()
        show_console()  # for hide if hidden
        self.sh = pc.console.shell
        self.activeLayerChanged()
```