# Opening the PyQGIS editor programmatically

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I can open the console programmatically, using:

```
qgis.utils.iface.actionShowPythonDialog().trigger()
```

Is there a way to additionally open the console's editor (the window where you can enter multiple lines of code)?

Comment: Look at the answers of https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/358508/93097

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need find the widget and after the QAction,It doesn't have a direct method in PyQGIS

```
consoleWidget = iface.mainWindow().findChild( QDockWidget, 'PythonConsole' )
consoleWidget.console.showEditorButton.trigger()
```

To find the name of the objects look at the source code

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/cce5c4e80265a7797c2b9fb9219ccad0238b6d04/python/console/console.py#L300

Or, this other way , based on this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/358580/49538

```
from console import console
console._console.console.showEditorButton.trigger()
```

Comment: Both work, amazing! Cool how you can trigger a click on that button, wasn't aware of that.